# Reallocating method for HashSet

Tags: java, dynamic, hash, hashset

I need to create a reallocate method for a HashSet. I will implement to an add and to a remove method, that way I increase or decrease its size if the load factor is greater than 1 or less than 0.5, respectively. The loadFactor = elements/size of the set. This is my work so far but I start losing elements whenever I need to increase the size of my set.

```
public void reallocate() {
    double loadFactor = (double) currentSize / buckets.length;
    Node[] newBuckets;
    if (loadFactor > 1) {
        newBuckets = new Node[buckets.length * 2];
        for (Node bucket : buckets) {
            if (bucket != null) {
                int h = bucket.hashCode();
                h = Math.abs(h % newBuckets.length);
                newBuckets[h] = bucket;
            }
        }
        buckets = newBuckets;
    } else if (loadFactor < 0.5) {
        newBuckets = new Node[buckets.length / 2];
        for (Node bucket : buckets) {
            if (bucket != null) {
                int h = bucket.hashCode();
                h = Math.abs(h % newBuckets.length);
                newBuckets[h] = bucket;
            }
        }
        buckets = newBuckets;
    }
}
```

The original array is buckets and I create newBuckets with the selected size. Used the loop to copy each element to newBuckets and then set buckets = newBuckets. I would prefer some advice instead of handing me the solution since I want to learn how to do this.

Comment: You probably need to re-hash the existing entries into new buckets rather than just moving the old buckets around whole.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to automatically decrease the size. A common use case when filling hash sets is to allocate it to the desired size and then start filling it. That prevents having to re-allocate multiple times when you have a large number of items to add.